# Index is only up to 1 in swift tableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

This code is SettingTableViewCell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xigu.png)

```
class SettingTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "SettingTableViewCell"
    
    private let iconContainer = UIView().then {
        $0.clipsToBounds = true
        $0.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        $0.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
    
    private let iconImageView = UIImageView().then {
        $0.tintColor = .white
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
    
    private let label = UILabel().then {
        $0.numberOfLines = 1
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        [label, iconImageView, iconContainer].forEach { contentView.addSubview($0) }
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let size: CGFloat = contentView.frame.size.height - 12
        iconContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: size, height: size)
        let imageSize: CGFloat = size/1.5
        iconImageView.frame = CGRect(x: (size-imageSize)/2, y: (size-imageSize)/2, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
        iconImageView.center = iconContainer.center
        
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 20 + iconContainer.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.size.width - 20 - iconContainer.frame.size.width, height: contentView.frame.size.height)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        iconImageView.image = nil
        label.text = nil
        iconContainer.backgroundColor = nil
    }
    
    public func configure(with model: SettingOption) {
        label.text = model.title
        iconImageView.image = model.icon
        iconContainer.backgroundColor = model.iconBackgroundColor
    }
}
```

this code is SettingViewController

```
import UIKit

struct Section {
    let title: String
    let options: [SettingsOptionType]
}

enum SettingsOptionType {
    case staticCell(model: SettingOption)
    case switchCell(model: SettingsSwitchOption)
}

struct SettingsSwitchOption {
    let title: String
    let icon: UIImage?
    let iconBackgroundColor: UIColor
    let handler: (() -> Void)
    var isOn: Bool
}

struct SettingOption {
    let title: String
    let icon: UIImage?
    let iconBackgroundColor: UIColor
    let handler: (() -> Void)
}



final class SettingViewController: UIViewController {
    private lazy var presenter = SettingPresenter(viewController: self)
    
    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        table.register(SettingTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SettingTableViewCell.identifier)
        table.register(SwitchTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: SwitchTableViewCell.identifier)
        
        return table
    }()
    
    var models = [Section]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        configure()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    func configure() {
        //스위치 관련
//        models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
//            .switchCell(model: SettingsSwitchOption(title: "Airplane Mode", icon: UIImage(systemName: "airplane"), iconBackgroundColor: .systemRed, handler: {
//
//            }, isOn: true))
//        ]))
        
//        models.append(Section(title: "개인정보", options: [
//            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "gmail", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .green, handler: {
//                print("asdfasdf")
//            })),
//            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "아이디 정보", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .green, handler: {
//                print("sdfgsdfgsdfg")
//            }))
//        ]))
        
        models.append(Section(title: "개인정보", options: [
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "gmail 정보", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                    let idVC = IdInformationViewController()
                    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(idVC, animated: true)
                    print("클릭함")
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "아이디 정보", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {

                print("하하")
            })
        ]))
//
        
        models.append(Section(title: "보안", options: [
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "앱 비밀번호", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "침입 시도", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "앱 열기 추적", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                print("asdfasdf r")
            })
        ]))
        
        models.append(Section(title: "앱", options: [
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "앱 아이콘 변경", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "앱 테마 변경", icon: UIImage(systemName: "bluetooth"), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            })
        ]))
        
        models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "지원", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "버그 보고하기", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            })
        ]))
        
        models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "피드백", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            })
        ]))
        
        models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "앱 공유", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "개인정보 처리 방침", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "이용 약관", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            })
        ]))
        
        models.append(Section(title: "", options: [
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "사용 방법", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            }),
            .staticCell(model: SettingOption(title: "개발자 정보", icon: UIImage(systemName: ""), iconBackgroundColor: .gray) {
                
            })
        ]))
    }
}

extension SettingViewController: SettingProtocol {
    
}

extension SettingViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        let section = models[section]
        return section.title
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        print("numberOfSections \(models.count)")
        return models.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(" numberOfRowsInSection \(models[section].options.count)")
        return models[section].options.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let model = models[indexPath.section].options[indexPath.row]
        print("model: \(model)")
        switch model.self {
        case .staticCell(let model):
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: SettingTableViewCell.identifier,
                for: indexPath) as? SettingTableViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            cell.configure(with: model)
            return cell
        case .switchCell(let model):
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
                withIdentifier: SwitchTableViewCell.identifier,
                for: indexPath) as? SwitchTableViewCell else {
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            cell.configure(with: model)
            return cell
        }

    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        let type = models[indexPath.row].options[indexPath.row]
        switch type.self {
        case .staticCell(let model):
            model.handler()
        case .switchCell(let model):
            model.handler()
        }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THTHU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAJjc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeHeM.png)

this code is SwitchTableViewCell

```
import UIKit
import Then

class SwitchTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "SwitchTableViewCell"
    
    private let iconContainer = UIView().then {
        $0.clipsToBounds = true
        $0.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        $0.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
    
    private let iconImageView = UIImageView().then {
        $0.tintColor = .white
        $0.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
    
    private let label = UILabel().then {
        $0.numberOfLines = 1
    }
    
    private let mySwitch = UISwitch().then { $0.onTintColor = .systemBlue }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        
        [label, iconContainer, mySwitch].forEach { contentView.addSubview($0) }
        iconContainer.addSubview(iconImageView)
        
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        accessoryType = .none
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let size: CGFloat = contentView.frame.size.height - 12
        iconContainer.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 6, width: size, height: size)
        let imageSize: CGFloat = size/1.5
        iconImageView.frame = CGRect(x: (size-imageSize)/2, y: (size-imageSize)/2, width: imageSize, height: imageSize)
        iconImageView.center = iconContainer.center
        
        mySwitch.sizeToFit()
        mySwitch.frame = CGRect(x: contentView.frame.size.width - mySwitch.frame.size.width - 10, y: (contentView.frame.size.height - mySwitch.frame.size.height)/2, width: mySwitch.frame.size.width, height: mySwitch.frame.size.height)
        
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 20 + iconContainer.frame.size.width, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.size.width - 20 - iconContainer.frame.size.width, height: contentView.frame.size.height)
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        
        iconImageView.image = nil
        label.text = nil
        iconContainer.backgroundColor = nil
        mySwitch.isOn = false
    }
    
    public func configure(with model: SettingsSwitchOption) {
        label.text = model.title
        iconImageView.image = model.icon
        iconContainer.backgroundColor = model.iconBackgroundColor
        mySwitch.isOn = model.isOn
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWue6.png)

I'm setting up iOS, but I don't know if it's because tableView overlaps, but if indexPath is only up to 1, and indexPath.row is 0, the 0th of all cells is the same as the first declared result.

To give you a little bit more detail, the function configure automatically gives each model an interval when the model comes in, so it fits the cell price index.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmfVk.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/362s2.png)

I want the index of all cells to be different, so if I put the value in the header and click on it, the events in the header will be executed.